# Simple encryption

Tags: java, string, encryption

I'm developing a game and i need to save some data files that will hold protected data, my goal is that no one will be able to read / edit the file, I have coded a simple byte manipulation algorthim:

```
private static final int KEY = 25156;

public static String encrypt(String s) {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        bytes[i] = (byte) (bytes[i] + KEY);
    return new String(bytes);
}

public static String decrypt(String s) {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        bytes[i] = (byte) (bytes[i] - KEY);
    return new String(bytes);
}
```

Strings are not readable, but i have a few questions:

1. Can this solve my problem?
2. If not, what else can solve it?

Comment: Note that your "key" value will be interpreted modulo 256, meaning it's equivalent to 68.  And this is an incredibly simple, unsophisticated code that anyone with a bit of understanding can "crack".  It will prevent a naive user from reading the file, but that's about it.

Comment: If by "no one will be able to read/edit the file" you mean "no one can conveniently read/edit the file", yes, this will solve your problem. If you mean "no one, including government security agencies or other cryptographic specialists will be able to read/edit the file", you'll need a great deal more sophistication. Can you be a bit more specific in your question?

Comment: The reality is that a determined attacker will be able to decrypt your files if all code/encryption keys are local (which I assume they will be). If you are after a reasonably decent algorithm then look at the javax.crypto package which will allow you to encrypt data with a key embedded in your code so someone will have to decompile your code to be able to decrypt.

Comment: My problem is i cant have a non local key cause each time the application opens i need to decrypt a file, which i cannot do if the key is randomly generated

Comment: The typical way to "solve" this problem is to use a standard encryption algorithm (most platforms have something reasonably robust built in) and, for a key, generate a value based on the machine serial or some such, using an obfuscated process.  Of course we're constantly reminded that "obfuscation is not security", but you do what you can.  However, you can improve on it significantly (make it actually modestly secure) by requiring a password from the user on app startup and including that in the key computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest XOR encryption?

To encode OR decode:

```
public static String crypt(String s) {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        bytes[i] = (byte) (bytes[i] ^ KEY);
    return new String(bytes);
}
```

Calling `crypt("foo")` will encrypt. If you call crypt again, it will decrypt: `crypt(crypt("foo")) // returns "foo"`

To randomize it a bit more, you could start throwing in other variables:

```
bytes[i] = (byte) (bytes[i] ^ KEY ^ i ^ bytes.length);
```

Comment: Just checked what xor is about, how can I implement that in java?

Comment: That's not inherently different from his scheme -- probably even slightly less secure.